# Powershell get files from machine doesn't work when executed by Taskscheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a machine that I should read logdata from. The data is located at 192.168.1.151/traceability.
I wrote a little Script that should be able to return the the files. It does work when I manualy start it. But when I execute it with Windows Task Scheduler it is not able to get the files:

```
$WinAPI = @"
   public class WinAPI
   {
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = 
      System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
      public static extern void OutputDebugString(string message);
   }
"@
$Path = "\\192.168.1.151\traceability"
$items = get-childitem -Path $Path
[WinAPI]::OutputDebugString($items.Length);
```

The $items.Length is zero when it is executed by Task Scheduler and 3 if it is executed manualy.
The task is set to run with full priviledge on the Admin Account (same one that successfully tested the script).
I also tryed to map the path to Z: and use `$Path = "Z:\"` instead but that didn't help to solve the Problem.

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to get the files with Powershell.

Comment: What does the access logs on `192.168.1.151` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the Problem by doing the mapping inside the Powershellscript:

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("p:", $Path, $false, "user", "password")
```

That way the Admin user is able to access the files.